# Filter out merged branch history in SmartGit Log view

Tags: git, smartgit

SmartGit has something I have always wanted which is the ability to select which branches are shown in a commit graph.     However, there's one thing I find somewhat annoying.

If I have selected to include branches X and Y, it insists on showing the entire commit history of every branch that was merged into X or Y.

Is there a way to suppress this?

Or does anyone know of a GUI git tool that allows you to select the included branches and suppress this?  What I'm basically looking for is a very simple view of two branches and finding where they intersect with minimal extra "noise".

I should also mention that this is a "means to an end", and that the true goal here is that people on my project often forget what branch "this branch" was cut from.

Here's a screenshot with the stuff I'd like to see suppressed indicated in red:

REDACTED

Comment: Contained sensitive information

Answer (score 2):

SmartGit 18.2 has an experimental option to only show first-parent commits (option in the **Commits** view hamburger-menu). To enable experimental features, you have to set **Low-level Property** (in the **Preferences**) `experimentalFeaturesEnabled` to `true`.